# Unknown CA when testing Mosquitto SSL config on Debian

Tags: debian, mosquitto

I'm working on a Debian VM in Microsoft Azure.
I installed Mosquitto and it runs fine while I don't configure SSL.
I created a self-signed certificate and keys (server.crt & server.key) with OpenSSL :

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 360
```

My hostname is Debian-RNO and I used it as common name.
My mosquitto.conf is

```
# mosquitto.conf
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
# MQTT over TLS/SSL
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
tls_version tlsv1.2
# End of MQTT over TLS/SLL configuration
```

The broker starts without error.
When I exec a mosquitto_pub like :

```
mosquitto_pub -h Debian-RNO -t topic1 -m "test" -d --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt -p 8883
```

I received this error :

```
Unable to connect (A TLS error occurred.).
```

In mosquitto.log, I have those entries :

```
1507583871: New connection from 52.178.101.16 on port 8883.
1507583871: OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
1507583871: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure
1507583871: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

I searched for hours without success... Any help is welcome!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue when running mosquitto_pub through cmd windows

Comment: @JN_newbie do you remember if you found any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

This clearly tells that during ssl handshake, CA certificate is not trusted as it's signed by your locally generated CA so you need to import your CA certificate in the trust-store(operating system level or whichever truststore mosquitto is using)

Comment: But mosquitto is using the mosquitto.conf where the certificate location is described, right? https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html